# Unity 5 mecanim animation controlled by UI slider

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a slider to control an animation in my scene. I need to the length of the slider to match the length of the animation and when I scrub the slider, the animation should play the appropriate part.

```
 public Slider slider;
public Animator animator;

void Start()
{
    slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnValueChanged);
}

private void OnValueChanged(float changedValue)
{
    animator.speed = 0;
    animator.Play("yourAnimationName", -1, slider.normalizedValue);
}
```

I have also placed this on my slider components on value changed section but the two still do not synch up. What is it I'm doing wrong / missing?

*edit*
updated code sample and removed the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is quite clear about it. Delegate has to have float parameter. Change

```
private void OnValueChanged()
```

to

```
private void OnValueChanged(float changedValue)
```

**Update:**

Don't set the animation speed to 0:

```
public Slider slider;
public Animator animator;

void Start()
{
    animator.speed = 0.00001f;
    slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnValueChanged);
}

private void OnValueChanged(float changedValue)
{
    animator.speed = 0.00001f;
    animator.Play("yourAnimationName", -1, slider.normalizedValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I ammended my code, but my animation and slider still aren't sinking up. Which is the real issue im having